# "Private feedback for you" reappears

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

I post a question, someone voted it as duplicate and this form appears:

---

[image]

---

After I click "Submit" button following popup appears (notice there is no form anymore):

---

[image]

---

But after closing it and hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or opening my question I see form again! I submit it several times already.

Comment: Perhaps you change your mind? Perhaps a new answer is added to a dupe target? Perhaps another duplicate was added to the list? - These are reasons as to why it should reappear... or... perhaps it's because it asked you to edit your question and you didn't?

Comment: @NickA, no, no, no, yes. So it annoys me to force me to edit? But why resubmitting? What does submitting actually do? Someone sits there and reads all this submits? And what he is doing afterwards? I guess shall I click "yes", my question is immediately doomed and auto-closed as duplicate... so all this nightmare will stops...

Comment: @Sinatr: *or* you can edit your question to show how it is unique. You could have read the answers of the other two posts and explained why those don't answer your question, for example. You didn't edit the post, so there was no way for the system to know you didn't *accidentally* choose 'no' and hit submit.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not saying you actually did change your mind or that new answers/dupes were added, I'm saying they're *potential* reasons why it should reappear, it may happen in future, it may not. And it *should* force you to edit, the onus is on you as the author to *prove* your post isn't a duplicate

Comment: @MartijnPieters, didn't consider that system may try to *care* about me.. I like that *accidental no* protection.. that's.. solid reason. I will edit my question next time and better this form be gone then!

Comment: Sorry but these are bad comments. A UI that won't accept an an answer in case you didn't mean it? A system that assumes you are in the wrong? If I don't think it IS a dupe I should not have to edit my post, I should be able to acknowledge the prompt. If people agree it's a dupe, it will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with this component where it only worked part of the time. It should now work in all cases. I have also added functionality to it to delete the "is this a duplicate" comment that is associated with the flags that have been rejected by the asker (flags as still valid for closing even if asker rejects them).

Comment: What do you mean with that second sentence? Selecting _No_ doesn't mean a possible duplicate flag gets rejected, right, since the OP shouldn't be able to unilaterally reject flags?

Comment: With the flag that is rejected by the OP. It is still a valid flag and and will be treated as such in the close queue.

Comment: So what to expect now? After clicking "Submit" the form should not reappears anymore, right? And btw I wouldn't delete comment. Future readers can't see if someone has already found the correct duplicate easily. Otherwise they have to notice there is a close-vote, click on "close", then choose "duplicate of ..." and only then can see which duplicates are currently associated.