# Why does "Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem" keep coming back?

Tags: support, bug

[image]

I've noticed this recently and it seems a neat feature as a precursor to closure that you might have a duplicate or might be able to clarify, rather than have to re-open, if you can get to it in time. At least I assume that is the motivation for it.

However submitting an answer doesn't appear to do anything. The popup goes away but if you reload the page, there is is again. Is this a bug or intended behaviour? Is my answer recorded anywhere?

Also does this feature have a name?

Comment: Looks like a prettier version of the existing notice that had asked a similar question and had two buttons rather than radio buttons and a submit button. I would expect that selecting Yes and hitting Submit would close the question. Selecting No... would not? I have no idea :).

Comment: Comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392983/private-feedback-for-you-reappears) are speculative, but no official feedback on it AFAIK

Comment: I wonder if it's common across SE sites